# Literal values in object type inference

Tags: typescript

This is quite verbose:

```js
interface Point {
  x: 1;
  y: 2;
}

const point: Point = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
};

// The inferred type would have been
// { x: number; y: number; }
```

Is there any way to use type inference here but to force values to be literals?

Comment: I don't understand the question or problem. Why does Point in the inferred type have `string` instead of `number`? How can primitive types be used as values? Only literal types can be used as JavaScript values, so I don't get what you mean by forcing keys to be literals.

Comment: Sorry I meant `number` not `string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `as const`:

```js
const point = {
  x: '1',
  y: '2',
} as const; // { x: '1'; y: '2'; }
```